# Can't edit files as su in home folder on OS X, CSRutil notwithstanding

Tags: bash, permissions, osx-elcapitan, su

When I start a terminal session I get the following message:

```
mkdir: /Users/MY_USERNAME/.bash_sessions: Operation not permitted
```

This "operation not permitted" persists when I sudo the command, and also when I enable root user.

I have rebooted holding <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and disabled csr.

```
$ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.

$ ls -ld ~/
drwxr-xr-x+ 123 MY_USERNAME  staff   4.1K Feb  8 11:38 /Users/MY_USERNAME/
```

Please help. I cannot edit, add files in my `~/` directory. I cannot access bash history and no bash history is recorded. Running El Capitan (10.11.4 Build 15E65). The issue started around when I upgraded to El Capitan — Thanks.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the related site http://apple.stackexchange.com (AskDifferently). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: Make sure your user directory has the correct file permissions.
`sudo chown -R YOUR_USERNAME ~/`